# Can't process set operations after client evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
var result = result.Select(a => new Subject
{
    Problem = 
        a.BaseProblem
            .Select(baseProblem => new ProblemDTO
            {
                Comment = baseProblem.CommentsModel.Select(c => new CommentDTO 
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Text = c.Text
                })
            })
        .Union(a.UserProblem
            .Select(userProblem => new ProblemDTO
                {
                    Comment = userProblem.CommentsModel.Select(e => new CommentDTO 
                    {
                        Id = e.Id,
                        Text = e.Text
                    })
                }))
});
```

I just need to get the Problem List and the relevant Comment list for each Problem.

> Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation before the last 'Select' call.

It does not give any compile error but when I run the code it will give the above-mentioned error.

Comment: EF is perfectly capable of loading related entities if you just tell it about them and that you want them loaded. Is there a reason you're trying to do this manually instead?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes. I have to do it in this way.

Comment: `I have to do it in this way` no you don't. That's almost always a bug - as in 99.999999....% of cases. What are you trying to do and *why* ?

Comment: That `Union` smells like an unconfigured inheritance hierarchy for example. With proper configuration all this could be replaced with `_db.Problems.Include(p=>p.Comments).Select(p=>new ProblemDTO{ ...})`

Comment: I have to follow some pattern that's why I mentioned that way. 
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16243 This is one solution. But the problem is applying this to my situation.

Comment: @zacknight95 _"I have to follow some pattern that's why"_ -  **who** says you have to follow what "pattern" and **why?**